# django invalid field name(s) for model content type

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

i looked all around internet i can't find a solution for this error in django
this script is worked on by one of the developers before me
i'm trying to run

```
./manage.py migrate
```

but it keeps getting this output

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Invalid field name(s) for model ContentType: 'name'.
```

and [this](https://pastebin.com/F5Wnq3dk) is the whole traceback

this is the content of manage.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "smsg.settings")

from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Can you please provide the model where this field is declared?

Comment: Can you share the complete error message?

Comment: it is in the documentation that he sent me a while ago everything else is ok but when i get to this command it keeps getting the same error

Comment: @SagunShrestha https://pastebin.com/F5Wnq3dk

Comment: Which version of Django are you using?

Comment: @SagunShrestha 1.11

Comment: Can you share the code of your models?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/EqRscpDp

Answer (score 0):

In your function create_custom_permission you try to create a ContentType with name in the args and no model.

Content type has no field name, name is a function [returning the verbose name of the linked model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType).

I don't know what you're tying to do but you're using the wrong tool.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the `create_custom_permissions()` function in models.py. This function tries to create permission with

```
ct, created = ContentType.objects.get_or_create(model='', app_label='smsapp', name='view cards')
```

and fails, because `ContentType` model does not have a `name` field.

Comment: What do you mean by "assigned a name"? What exactly did you do?